# PreparedStatement executeUpdate on an OracleDataSource connection does not auto commit

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, java-8, java-7

Call to preparedStatement.executeUpdate() returns successfully (with count of rows updated). But the DB does not reflect the update. Seeing this issue with ojdbc7.jar (tried both java 7 and java 8 SEs).

```
final String UPDATE_SQL = "UPDATE myPortfolio SET stock = ? WHERE key = ?";
    final String stock = 'SO';// pre ipo :)
    final long key = 12345l;

    try (Connection conn = pds.getConnection(); PreparedStatement proc = conn.prepareStatement(UPDATE_SQL)) {
        //conn.setAutoCommit(false); --> this works
        conn.setAutoCommit(true); // this is the default...but making sure
        proc.setString(1, stock);
        proc.setLong(2, key);
        int rowcount = proc.executeUpdate();
        //conn.commit(); --> this works

        logger.info("Updated {} rows. SQL = {}. stock = {}, key = {}, InboundKey = {}", rowcount, UPDATE_SQL, stock, key);
        // logs 1 row updated. But DB still shows stale data (old stock) for key 12345l.
    } catch (SQLException E) {
        throw new PersistenceException(E);
    }

    // Pool data source settings
    PoolDataSource        pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
    pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
    pds.setConnectionPoolName(cacheName);
    pds.setURL(dbUrl);
    pds.setUser(username);
    pds.setPassword(password);

    pds.setMinPoolSize(5);
    pds.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    pds.setInitialPoolSize(7);
    pds.setInactiveConnectionTimeout(10);
```

Comment: Either call `conn.commit()` or enable the `autoCommit` option.

Comment: @Brandon, I have conn.setAutoCommit(true). what more must I do to enable auto commit?

Comment: Oh I didn't see that.  I am not familiar with `PoolDataSource`.  It looks like an Oracle connection pool library.  I can't find any pool-level auto-commit settings.  I'm really not sure.

Comment: How are you using the variable `pds` before it is declared? You should post a verifiable example rather than a piece of code that *can’t* work. Besides that, it looks like an Oracle issue that should be handled by Oracle’s customer support…

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the executeUpdate() or execute() then you need to do the        connection.commit().
    And if you dont want to execute the commit then you can go for :prepareStatement() does not require a commit().